# How to uninstall a Windows program from Wine?

Tags: wine

I have installed several Windows programs using Wine. The problem is that I wont to uninstall some of them because I don't need them. And I wont to that without affecting the Windows apps that I wont to keep. But I can't see any way to uninstall them! Even if I explore drive C trough Wine I can't find any unistall.exe file for them although I can find the install.exe

Please, help me in this, even if it may sound childish. I think I can't find the solution because I am still influenced by some kind of "Windows mentality" wich makes me blind to such an easy solution.

Thanks!